# ASP dropdownlist databind from database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using 2 dropdownlist. 1st for country and 2nd for states. If I select India from 1ft dropdownlist, the 2nd one is automatically bind all the states of India automatically from database.

I have used `country_tbl` for countries and bind with 1st dropdownlist and `india_tbl`, `us_tbl`, `sri_tbl` for binding states regarding these countries.

Please help me. What should I do?

My code is as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        method1();
    }
}

protected void method1()
{
    string s1 = "data source=ALOK-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;database=MySite;integrated security=true";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(s1);
    string s2 = "select * from country";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s2, con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "name";
    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "name";
    DropDownList1.DataSource = dr;
    DropDownList1.DataBind();
    con.Close();
    dr.Close();
}

protected void methodInd()
{
    string s1 = "data source=ALOK-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;database=MySite;integrated security=true";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(s1);
    string s2 = "select * from india";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s2, con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DropDownList2.DataTextField = "name";
    DropDownList2.DataValueField = "name";
    DropDownList2.DataSource = dr;
    DropDownList2.DataBind();
    con.Close();
    dr.Close();
}

protected void methodpak()
{
    string s1 = "data source=ALOK-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;database=MySite;integrated security=true";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(s1);
    string s2 = "select * from pakistan";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s2, con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DropDownList2.DataTextField = "name";
    DropDownList2.DataValueField = "name";
    DropDownList2.DataSource = dr;
    DropDownList2.DataBind();
    con.Close();
    dr.Close();
}

protected void methodsri()
{
    string s1 = "data source=ALOK-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;database=MySite;integrated security=true";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(s1);
    string s2 = "select * from srilanka";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s2, con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DropDownList2.DataTextField = "name";
    DropDownList2.DataValueField = "name";
    DropDownList2.DataSource = dr;
    DropDownList2.DataBind();
    con.Close();
    dr.Close();
}

protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text=="india")
    {
        methodInd();
    }
    else if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text=="pakistan")
    {
        methodpak();
    }
    else if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text=="srilanka")
    {
        methodsri();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have different table for each country ? Are you sure you are doing it right ? You can keep all States in a single table and have a CountryID column to indentify `this states belongs to which country`. You may query it like `SELECT ID,NAME FROM STATE WHERE COUNTRY_ID=theCountryId`

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is wrong, you should not have separate tables for states of each country so you can have one query and one method to bind to your state list

Change your schema to

```
CREATE TABLE Country 
(
  id int,  
  country_name,
  primary key(id)
)

Country_State 
(
  id  int, 
  state_name, 
  country_id,
  primary key(id)
)
```

The country_id is the Foreign key that links back to the country

```
country
------------------------
id  Name
------------------------
1   India
2   Pakistan


country_state
-----------------------------------
id  Name              country_id
------------------------------------
1   Delhi             1
2   Bangladesh        1
3   Some Indians      1
4   S1_Pakistan       2
5   S2_Pakistan       2
```

Your queries

```
Select Id, Name from Country

Select Id, Name From country_states Where country_id = @id
```

> Call just one method to bind all states

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string country_id =  DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
     BindStatesByCountry(country_id);
}

protected void methodsri(string countryId) //change this to BindStatesByCountry
{
    string s1 = "data source=ALOK-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;database=MySite;integrated security=true";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(s1);
    con.Open();

    string s2 = "select * from country_states where country_id=@countryId";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s2, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@countryId", countryId);
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DropDownList2.DataTextField = "name";
    DropDownList2.DataValueField = "name";
    DropDownList2.DataSource = dr;
    DropDownList2.DataBind();
    con.Close();
    dr.Close();
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

you want to implement a master detail  pattern so see this url:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581789.aspx
Prefer stored procedure insteadof sql injection
Best regard