# Bug in my code or Am not doing it right

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have been struggling with the usecase for two days now.All i need was to read Patient'S VisitNumber from the patient visit table and populate the dropdownlist given the Patient Number.After some much research these two links address almost the same issue.I did as described here  [sample on stackover site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11592266/asp-dropdownlist-databind-from-database) but still mine is not working and no error is displayed. [Another sample is described here](http://aspdotnetcode.blogspot.com/2010/10/dropdownlist.html)!
Here is my codes:HTML

```
  <li>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID ="lblVisits">Visit Number</asp:Label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="174px" style="margin-left: 46px">
                <asp:ListItem Text=""></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value=""></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
  </li>
```

CodeBehind:

```
protected void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connect = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db_connection"].ToString();
        string num = txtPatientNumber.ToString();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connect);
        string Statement = "SELECT Visit_Number FROM Visit "
          + "WHERE Patient_Number=@Patient_Number";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Statement, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Patient_Number", num);

        SqlDataReader reader;

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                DropDownList2.DataSource = reader;
                DropDownList2.DataTextField = reader["Visit_Number"].ToString();
                DropDownList2.DataValueField = reader["Visit_Number"].ToString();
                DropDownList2.DataBind();
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (SqlException excep)
        {
            //Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('Patient Number not Found.');</script>");
            ErrorMessage.Text = "Error Occurred" + excep.Message.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: All the two example urls point to fake pages at example.com. You may want to fix that.

Comment: Instead of DropDownList2.DataTextField = reader["Visit_Number"].ToString();
Use    DropDownList2.DataTextField = "Visit_Number";

Comment: I did that , the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem lies here:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
   DropDownList2.DataSource = reader;
   DropDownList2.DataTextField = reader["Visit_Number"].ToString();
   DropDownList2.DataValueField = reader["Visit_Number"].ToString();
   DropDownList2.DataBind();
}
```

Your are using `.DataTextField` and `.DataValueField` wrong. This is how it should look like:

```
DropDownList2.DataTextField = "Visit_Number";
DropDownList2.DataValueField ="Visit_Number";
```

Also you should not rebind DropDownList for every row returned from db. So remove `while (reader.Read())`.

Final code:

```
DropDownList2.DataSource = reader;
DropDownList2.DataTextField = "Visit_Number";
DropDownList2.DataValueField = "Visit_Number";
DropDownList2.DataBind();
```

Comment: The problem still persist @gzaxx.your sample is also [explained here:](http://aspdotnetcode.blogspot.com/2010/10/dropdownlist.html) but is definately not working for me and my sql is tested and working fine.

Comment: Well that is a long shot but is `txtPatientNumber` a TextBoxControl? If yes this line `txtPatientNumber.ToString();` is wrong and should be `txtPatientNumber.Text;`. If not can you try to remove from HTML those two `<ListItem>` from inside of `DropDownList` and see if it works now?

Comment: you are right i have try to debug but the while loop is not executing at all.

Comment: It is not executing because reader is not returning any values. So this SQL statment is wrong or you are passing wrong value to it.